# Expokit SDK 34 unknown error --assetPlugins

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm having issues starting expo after upgrading Expo SDK to version 34.

```
error: unknown option `--assetPlugins'

Metro Bundler process exited with code 1 Error: Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
```

Version:

- expo-cli: 3.0.10
- React native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz
- Expo sdkVersion: 34.0.0

I have deleted the node modules and reset the cache multiple times without success. I'm sure to have the right version in app.json and package.json

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Fix by deleting package-lock.json :)